# Spark GroupBy Multiple Columns With Or

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a usecase where i want to groupBy records if one attribute value is same across multiple columns

| RecordId | Personal Address | Business Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | A1 | A2 |
| R2 | A2 | A3 |
| R3 | A3 | A4 |

The groupBy of Personal Address and Business Address should give me: [R1, R2, R3] as output b/c for R1 - R2, A2 is common and for R2 - R3, A3 is common.

Expected Output:

| RecordId | GroupId |
| --- | --- |
| R1 | M1 |
| R2 | M1 |
| R3 | M1 |

All Records R1, R2, R3 are mapped to same group b/c all records have either Personal Address or Business Address in common.

I couldn't find out any way that spark can support this.

Comment: can you please your expected output

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I'm still not sure I get it. R3 and R1 don't have anything in common between themselves. Why are they in the same group? If we had a RecordId R4 with Personal Address A4 and Business Address A5, should it also belong to M1?

Comment: This would probably not be possible with a single groupby, but with a loop each time merging rows having a value in common, until no merge occur...